# remove rows where all columns are NA except 2 columns

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table`. I want to remove those rows where all columns except certain 2 columns are NA. For example:

I have a data.table like:

```
> ww2
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species index
 1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa     1
 2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa     2
 3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa     3
 4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa     4
 5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa     5
 6:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 dffdsdf     1
 7:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2 dffdsdf     2
 8:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 dffdsdf     3
 9:           NA          NA           NA          NA dffdsdf     4
10:           NA          NA           NA          NA dffdsdf     5
```

Its dput is:

```
    structure(list(Sepal.Length = c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5, 5.1, 4.9, 
4.7, NA, NA), Sepal.Width = c(3.5, 3, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.5, 3, 
3.2, NA, NA), Petal.Length = c(1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.4, 
1.4, 1.3, NA, NA), Petal.Width = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
0.2, 0.2, NA, NA), Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), class = "factor", .Label = c("setosa", "versicolor", 
"virginica", "dffdsdf")), index = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L)), .Names = c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", 
"Petal.Width", "Species", "index"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

In above data table I want to remove row number 9 and 10. Since my actual data table is really big and has a lot more columns, it is difficult to explicitly mention those columns which are NA. But the columns which are not NA are fixed (they are 2, and in this particular example they are `index` and `Species`.

I am looking for an efficient and fast solution to this.

Comment: @Pascal it is not. There the person wanted remove those rows where any column is NA (does not matter if 1 column or 2 columns or 3 columns are NA). But here, I want to remove those rows where a fixed number of columns are NAs.

Comment: The `dput` gives an error Error: unexpected '<' in "                                                                                                                                                                                 "

Comment: So just specify them in `.SDcols`? For example `ww2[!ww2[, Reduce('&', lapply(.SD, is.na)), .SDcols = -(Species:index)]]`

Comment: @user3664020  I am pretty sure the answer in the duplicate can be adapted.

Comment: @RonakShah i have edited the `dput` , please convert that to a `data.table`. using `dt <- data.table(df)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg `.SDcols` takes columns in what format? What if I want to pass 3 columns. `.SDcols = -c(Species, index, col3)` is not working.

Comment: Try `-c("Species", "index", "Sepal.Length")` Or if they are in order you can just do `-(Petal.Width:index)` for exmaple

Comment: If this works for you we could probably close this as a dupe.

Answer (score 4):

Given the data you provided, I would do something like:

```
library(dplyr)
na_rows = ww2 %>% 
            select(-Species, -index) %>% 
            is.na() %>% 
            rowSums() > 0

ww2 %>% 
  filter(!na_rows)

  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species index
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa     1
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa     2
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa     3
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa     4
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa     5
6          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 dffdsdf     1
7          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2 dffdsdf     2
8          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 dffdsdf     3
```

or more default R style (I like `dplyr`):

```
na_rows = rowSums(is.na(ww2[, .SD, .SDcols = !c('Species', 'index')]), with = FALSE])) > 0
ww2[!na_rows,]
```

Comment: Ok, `as.data.frame` ;)?