# Remove rows where all columns except one have NA values?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dateframe with three columns, one of which has a variable for participant ID with no NA values and the other two (target variables) have some scattered throughout. I'm trying to use the solution explained here ([remove rows where all columns are NA except 2 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33607970/remove-rows-where-all-columns-are-na-except-2-columns)) to remove rows where both of the target variables have NAs, but for some reason my implementation of it seems to indiscriminately remove all NAs.

Here is a sample of what the unprocessed df looks like:

| ID | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ab | NA |
| 1 | NA | ab |
| 1 | NA | NA |

Here is what I want the processed df to look like:

| ID | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ab | NA |
| 1 | NA | ab |

And here is the code I'm using to try to accomplish this:

```
na_rows = df %>% 
  select(-"ID") %>% 
  is.na() %>% 
  rowSums() > 0

processeddf <- df %>% 
  filter(!na_rows)
```

However, this code returns a df which has removed any row containing NA at all. So for the above sample, it would return an empty df. Where am I going wrong here? I can't figure out where my logical error is occurring.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We may use `if_all`  in `filter`- select the columns a to b in `if_all`, apply the `is.na` (check for NA), the output will be TRUE for a row if both a and b have NA, negate (`!`) to convert TRUE-> FALSE and FALSE->TRUE

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   filter(!if_all(a:b, is.na))
```

-output

```
ID    a    b
1  1   ab <NA>
2  1 <NA>   ab
```

---

Or instead of negating (`!`), we may use `complete.cases` with `if_any`

```
df %>% 
  filter(if_any(a:b, complete.cases))
  ID    a    b
1  1   ab <NA>
2  1 <NA>   ab
```

---

Regarding the issue in OP's code, the logic is created by looking whether there is atleast one NA (`> 0`) which is true for all the rows.  Instead, it should be all NA and then negate

```
na_rows <- df %>% 
  select(-"ID") %>% 
  is.na() %>% 
  {rowSums(.) == ncol(.)}
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L), a = c("ab", NA, NA), b = c(NA, 
"ab", NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 3):

And additionally a data.table solution (thanks for the data akrun).

```
library(data.table)
dt = structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L), a = c("ab", NA, NA), 
                 b = c(NA, "ab", NA)), class = "data.table", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

dt[!(is.na(a) & is.na(b))]
```

**Output:**

```
   ID    a    b
1:  1   ab <NA>
2:  1 <NA>   ab
```